# Automated transcoding H.264 video on Linux

Tags: java, video, transcoding, h.264

I've got a video camera that I'm using to capture video; the camera records in H.264 at 720p resolution.  I'd like to transcode this stuff to a simpler, smaller format; something that will work properly on digital photo frames that support video, for example.  As well, I'd like to transcode to DVD format where possible, so I can burn DVDs for family members.  And I'd like this process to be accessible from within Java, so I can set up a server at home to do the transcoding and I can manage the process over the Web from work.

What's the best way to programmatically do transcoding from within Java?  What libraries exist for H.264 support, and how do I access them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try **ffmpeg for Java** http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php

ffmpeg is used for all kinds of transcoding/recoding ... it powers VLC!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler).  It automatically integrates with the latest FFmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is, you want to upload a video, have it re-encoded and then download the result... I would use php to call ffmpeg. Or you could use java with the ffmpeg-java support that Aiden Bell referenced.

If the videos will be on your computer, and you just want to control the process from work. Look into using a VNC server on your computer at home, and then using a java-based VNC viewer at work. This would allow you to transcode your videos, and work on anything else you want to on your home computer.